# Ubuntu 12.04 updater not working

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager, software-sources

This is the error I keep on getting when I try to update anything.

```
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal Release.gpg
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal Release
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal/main amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal/restricted amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal/main i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal/restricted i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5) quantal/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                                
Get:1 http//repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease [2,840 B]                                    
Err http//archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources

Ign http//archive.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_US

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

FYI: I had to erase a bunch of stuff cause it wouldn't let me post all the links or whatever in the report.

Answer (score 1):

12.10 is an unsupported release.  You can't depend on its software repositories being maintained anymore.

Your only valid upgrade path from 12.04 would be directly to 14.04 - the next LTS release.

- Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=lts`
- Run `do-release-upgrade` in a terminal.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question - I thought my answer covered that? You can upgrade from 12.04 straight to 14.04 by following my instructions above.  You can't upgrade to 12.10.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I misunderstood what you first said.  What do you mean by edit though?

Comment: Okay, so I got to where the Prompt=normal is, but it keeps saying permission denied when I try to save the changes as lts

Comment: [ Error writing /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades: Permission denied ]

Comment: You'll need superuser (root) rights to save that file.  Eg if you use nano, it's `sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`